# How to pass array of the object from page to component in Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am developing an app, using **Ionic 3** with **angular 4**. And I have the following problem: How can I pass an array of the object from a page, to a component?
When I inform the object in my directive to the component, it is converted to a string with the following information:
`[Object object], [Object object], [Object object]` ...

Page.html (page) code:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let telemetry of listTelemetry">
    <telemetria-chart medicao="{{telemetry.medicoes}}"></telemetria-chart>
</ion-card>
```

Original value of 'telemetry.medicoes' :
[image]

TelemetriaChart.ts (compenent) code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'telemetria-chart',
  templateUrl: 'telemetria-chart.html'
})
export class TelemetriaChartComponent {

  @ViewChild('myChart') canvas: ElementRef;

  @Input() funcionalidadeId: any;
  @Input() medicao: any [];

  text: string;

  constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('this.medicao', this.medicao);
      //...do something with this.medicao     
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

Result from console.log(this.medicao):
[image]

I need to get info from 'this.medicao'.

Comment: I do not understand you want to set single object from medicao array or all medicao array. And what data listTelemetry. Before you answer this questions fix these problems: [medicao]="telemetry.medicoes". You need to use [ ]. And not need to use {{ }}. Because we do not stringify it. Read here https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax

Comment: Thanks @RomaSkydan, I'll make a correction. I expressed myself, the doubt was so much for single object for list of object. But the list is a priority.

Comment: @RomaSkydan, your suggestion to switch medicao = "{{telemetry.medicoes}}" to [medicao] = "telemetry.medicoes", it worked! Thank you. Do you want to write your answer?

Comment: do we fix your problem? Or something left?

Comment: yeah, it's fix my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
medicao="{{telemetry.medicoes}}"
```

to

```
[medicao]="telemetry.medicoes"
```

Helpful link for you:

[Angular Interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#interpolation)

There you can read about `{{}}`. Where we need use and what interpolation do with data inserted in it.

[Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

And there you can read about component communication scenarios that we can use in angular2